# What damage can a thief do with a scanned image of a passport?

Tags: passports

My daughter, who lives and works in Hong Kong, applied on line for a visa to visit Vietnam. She scanned her passport, paid about $200 using a credit card and received a fake visa. She cancelled her credit card. I am concerned about what kind of identity theft she may be exposed to.  Fortunately, she did not provide her social security # or drivers license number and she physically has possession of her passport. However, the thieves have her picture, passport # and date of birth. Appreciate all advice.

Comment: Is she a US citizen residing in HK? Did she report this to HK police?

Comment: Yes, she is a US citizen. Since the thieves were on-line, they could be anywhere, not necessarily HK.

Comment: As in Nate's link it can increase your risk of fraud. I would discuss with my bank as well as credit card issuer. The bank can mark the account for extra scrutiny in case thieves try to impersonate her.